# API failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

For our iOS application I am using AWS server and for a particular API I am always getting failed with error "API failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003. A server with the specified hostname could not be found."

I am using AFNetworking for making API request.

Any hints as to where I might be going wrong? Whether its as API/Server issue or a client/iOS side issue.

Comment: did you solve this, I have changed my DNS setting for mac but still getting this error in my app running on simulator

Comment: No I did not got the solution for this.

Comment: thanks I fixed it, I retype the url instead of pasting it from other place it seems encoding issue then it works fine

Answer (score 1):

This error would typically suggest a DNS related issue.. It had nothing to do with AFNetworking (except for maybe reporting the wrong error)

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 main reasons:

- a DNS related issue try to connect to another network.
- trying wrong url

in my case my url was encoded to another in background because of copying it from other file. when I delete the url and retype it then it works.